# C++ Definition of dllimport static data member not allowed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dllimport

I am trying to compile the source/headers of some software into a static library, but am running into this dll issue.  I haven't been able to run it down, and the standard #ifndef/#define _declspec(...) isn't working. I don't have a ton of C++ experience, so I'm probably just missing something important.  Any help would be appreciated.

The errors occur on the last 4 lines of the section of source code, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

The header and source are a bit too long for here, but this is the jist:

Header(.h):

```
#ifdef CONVERSIONDLL_EXPORTS
#define CONVERSIONDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define CONVERSIONDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#ifndef ConversionUtility_h
#define ConversionUtility_h

#include <Config.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

#include <PropertyFileHandler.h>
#include <GWProperties.h>
#include <PureDataS.h>
#include <PureDataI.h>

class MSR_EXPORT Conversions {

    Msr::GWFramework::Component::PropertyFileHandler propertyFileHandler_;
double sea_level_corr_;

    public:
        double static const PI;
        double static const DEGREES_PER_RADIAN;
        double static const FEET_PER_METER;
        unsigned short static RTCODE_WGS_1984_IDENTITY;
    ...
```

Source(.cpp):

```
#include <CountdownTimer.h>
#include "ConversionUtility.h"
#include <Rotation.h>
#include <MsrConversionErrorException.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <GWTime.h>
#include <GWManagerDefines.h>


double const Conversions::PI = 3.14159265359; // low precision: atan(1.0)*4;
double const Conversions::DEGREES_PER_RADIAN = 180/PI;
double const Conversions::FEET_PER_METER = 1/0.3048;
unsigned short Conversions::RTCODE_WGS_1984_IDENTITY = 341; // from TENA-TSPI tdl
```

Comment: `...into a static library, but am running into this dll issue` So, are you building a static library, or a dynamic library (a DLL)? Which way is it? `The errors occur on the last 4 lines` It might be helpful to know *what* errors occur, would you agree?

Comment: What's `MSR_EXPORT` and how, if at all, is it related to `CONVERSIONDLL_EXPORTS` and `CONVERSIONDLL_API`?

Comment: So what is the exact __compiler__ error?